# nasm array1.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized on Linux 32

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I am now using BACKTRACK 5 which is almost like ubuntu, a debian and its 32 bit, and I have ins talled nasm, I went to dr. paulcarter's assembly language tutorials and downloaded his sample programs (Linux). I went to the directory where the sample programs are and executed the following instruction

~/Desktop/linux-ex# nasm -f coff array1.asm

~/Desktop/linux-ex# gcc -o array1 array1.o array1c.c

array1.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

The above execution instructions have been provided in the source file comments
How can I make these and later my own programs work?

Comment: Isn't 'coff' format more of a Windows thing?

Comment: Use `nasm -felf array1.asm` or download [objconv](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv) and do `objconv -felf32 array1.o`

Answer (score 2):

The Linux kernel supports various binary formats.  `coff` is a particularly old one, and if the kernel still supports it at all, it might not be enabled in modern distributions.  Try `-f elf` instead of `-f coff`.

Comment: Right. Nasm's `-f coff` is for D.J. Delorie's 32-bit DOS-extended DJGPP (not even MS-coff). `-f elf` (or `-f elf32` - same thing) should be right here.